# How to edit tags in Wiki.js pages?

Tags: wiki.js

I have a `Wiki.js` 2.x server running with PostgreSQL. I'm using default theme.

When creating new page, there is input field for tags, but after creation I couldn't find the place to add/remove tags.

The question: how can I edit tags of my pages ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit the page (clicking the pencil button). And in the edit page, find the "Page" button at the top-right corner.
That is the place where you can edit the page properties (including tags).

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling mathjax in your config.yml and restart wiki.js

Comment: It actually was 2.x version. And mathjax - doesn't have any effect :-(